# When using CallableStatement, NUMBER type columns only can be recovered like BigDecimal

Tags: java, oracle, callable-statement

I'm using CallableStatement to pass the stored procedure parameters through Java.

But, when I try to get some "NUMBER" type value, I can't use :

```
CallableStatement.getLong(1)
```

Because, all the "NUMBER" params will come like BigDecimal.

Any idea ?

For example - inside database:

```
Procedure LookingForSomething(myNumber OUT NUMERIC);
```

From Java:

```
 Long myNumber = CallableStatement.getLong("myNumber"); - doesn't work
```

Comment: may i know what are you tring to get values, am i guess you are getting value which is return by procedure ?

Comment: yes, the output parameter is filled inside store procedure.

I pass some empty variable, and i can recover the same filled variable.

Comment: can you please post your calling satatement exactly what have you used ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JavaDocs of `CallableStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) the method `getLong` ...

> Retrieves the value of a JDBC BIGINT parameter as a long in the Java programming language.

while `getBigDecimal`...

> Retrieves the value of a JDBC NUMERIC parameter as a java.math.BigDecimal object with as many digits to the right of the decimal point as the value contains.

So as your database type is `NUMERIC` and not `BIGINT`, you have to use `getBigDecimal`.

`NUMERIC` is a data type with decimal places, so `long` can't hold all possible values as it is an integer data type.

If you are sure that you don't receive a fractional part and your number will fit into a `long`, you can use

```
long myNumber = CallableStatement.getNumeric("myNumber").longValue();
```

For details about `longValue()` you can have a look at the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#longValue()).